# Adding a youtube video inside android google v2 map marker

Tags: android, video, youtube, maps, marker

I'm trying to add a youtube video to a marker on Android Google Maps v2.

After looking at the Android docs my first thought was to add the html5 link to the .snippet() option but that doesn't seem to work.

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(MELBOURNE)
                        .title("Melbourne")
                        .snippet("<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_jh0PGodonk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Answer (score 2):

All markers in Google Android Maps Api v2 are clickable. You don't need to set any additional properties to your marker. What you need to do - is to register marker click callback to your googleMap and handle click within callback:

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
        implements OnMarkerClickListener
    {
        private Marker myMarker;    

        private void setUpMap()
        {
            .......
            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

            myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title("My Spot")
                        .snippet("This is my spot!")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            ......
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
            {
                //handle click here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what I am trying to do is add a video to the marker body so once the user clicks the marker: they see the title, description and a video block which if they click will play. It's more of a 'rendering video on marker issue' as my original code does not do this.

Comment: @user1686342 you can "clicked" on marker and open new activity showing your video on full screen.